# bilinear mapping from product of rationals to rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products, multilinear-algebra, universal-property

I'm trying to use the universal property of the tensor product to show the existence of a homomorphism from the tensor product $\mathbb{Q}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Q}$, but for some reason I can't seem to find a $\mathbb{Z}$-bilinear map $\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}$. Does there necessarily exist one?

Comment: How about $(p,q) \mapsto pq$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about 
$$f(\frac{p}{q},\frac{s}{t})=\frac{ps}{qt}$$
for a bilinear map?